# JQuery Algorithm for changing DIV offset if still in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm

hopefully you may be able to assist.

My example code:

http://jsfiddle.net/RevengerTT/YZtyj/1/

I'm trying to work out an algorithm which will capture the offset().left and work out if it has moved the DIV "stretchflex" out of the view state.

I'm really struggling to get my head around this (started JQuery coding today after watching a quick video).

I've worked in three variables I think should give me the values I need, but the issue I'm having is that `var z = $("#stretchflex").width()` doesn't represent the "actual" width of the DIV, but the visible width of it.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
        $("#SFPanLeft").click(function () {
            var x = $("#SFHolder").width()
            var y = $("#stretchflex").offset().left
            var z = $("#stretchflex").width()
            $("#x").html("X : " + x.toString());
            $("#y").html("Y : " + y.toString());
            $("#z").html("Z : " + z.toString());
            if (x > (z + y)) {            /* <----This is the bit which doesn't work */
                var left = $("#stretchflex").offset().left
                left -= 176
                $("#stretchflex").css({
                    left: left + 'px'
                });
            };
        });
```

Many thanks for your help in advance - can't think how many times I've found the answers I need by searching this site :)

Answer (score 0):

Think I've sorted this.

Just in case anyone finds this...

```
        $("#SFPanLeft").click(function () {
            var x = $("#SFHolder").width();
            var y = $("#stretchflex").offset().left;
            var z = $("#stretchflex").get(0).scrollWidth; /* using scrollWidth fixes */
            $("#x").html("X : " + x.toString());
            $("#y").html("Y : " + y.toString());
            $("#z").html("Z : " + z.toString());
            if (x < (z + y)) {                            /* updated algorithm */
                var left = $("#stretchflex").offset().left
                left -= 176
                $("#stretchflex").css({
                    left: left + 'px'
                });
            };
        });
```